# Thoughts on how to implement?

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list

I am porting some very old c-code into c++ and I've run across a linked list implemented within an array.  The element is a simple structure:

```
struct element
{
    void *m_ptrData;
    short m_nextEntry;
    short m_prevEntry;
};
```

As an array, there is quick access to the data, if you know the index.  The linked list aspect lets the elements be moved around, and "deleted" from the list.  Elements can be moved in the list, based on frequency of use (up for MRU and down for LRU).

I like to find a better way to implement this than using another array.  I'd like to use STL, but I'm not certain which container is best to use.

Any one have any thoughts?

Comment: Is random access speed crucial? I mean does it occur *a lot*, as opposed to iterating?

Comment: It depends entirely on how it's used by the rest of the code. Is direct access a common way of accessing elements, or is it done mostly by stepping through the list? Are some elements accessed more often than others?

Comment: I once read an article that claimed (and defended) the assertion that `std::vector` is almost always a better choice than `std::list`, even if you're adding/removing items from the middle of the container.  I can't find the article now, so I've added this as a comment instead of an answer.  I'd appreciate if some else who's aware of the article could post a link.

Comment: @Michael Burr: it almost always depends on how often you need to add/remove items, how many items you need to add/remove at a time, and what you do with the container afterward.

Comment: @Dima: I don't know of any specific article, but know from my own and other people's experience that, if copying is cheap enough, `std::vector` is almost always better that `std::list`, even if it shouldn't be in theory. It certainly is if you only store pointers. See my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Since this is a linked list, you should probably use [std::list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)...

The rule of thumb is that you want to use a linked list when you need to insert elements into random positions in the list, or delete random elements from the list.  If you mainly need to add/delete elements to/from the end of the list, then you should use `std::vector`.  If you need to add/delete elements to/from either beginning or the end of the list, then you should use `std::deque`.

Keep in mind, we are talking about probabilities here.  If you need to insert an element into the middle of an `std::vector` once in a blue moon, that will probably be ok.  But if you need to do this all the time, it will have a major impact on performance, because the vector will need to constantly move its elements, and probably reallocate its memory too.

On the other hand, the advantage of using a vector is that its elements are contiguous in memory, which greatly improves performance if you simply need to traverse them in order because of caching.

Comment: Direct access is the most common access

Comment: @kberson nb. that std::list doesn't support direct access by index.

Comment: Need to be able to directly access the elements with just the index.  Need to be able to move elements, so stl::vector doesn't work.

Comment: @Kberson:  If it worked using an array then it will DEFINITELY work with a std::vector ...

Comment: What do you mean by "move elements"?  If you need to swap two elements, there is no problem.  If you need to add more elements to the end of the vector, then it will grow automatically. But if you need to insert an element at, say, index 5, then the vector will have to move all the elements starting with number 5 up by one.

Comment: @kberson: notice that it's not that it's impossible for `std::vector` to insert elements in the middle - it's just that, because of the very nature of vectors, it's not that efficient, because all the elements after the insertion point have to be moved.

Answer (score 4):

Since the data in this list is pointers, why bother with a linked list at all? For small PODs, `std::vector` is usually the best first bet, and due to the better locality of its data playing nicely with processor caches it often out-performs a linked list even where, in theory, a linked list should be better. I'd pick `std::vector` until some profiling would show that there is a performance problem and `std::list` performs better.

Answer (score 3):

See here:

http://linuxsoftware.co.nz/cppcontainers.html

There's a flow chart to help you choose the right container at the bottom.